# Is it possible fo find a vertex-cover of size $\lceil \log |V| \rceil$ in polynomial time?

Tags: polynomial-time, vertex-cover

If we have a graph $G=(V,E)$, can we find a vertex cover with size $\lceil \log |V| \rceil$ in polynomial time?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes.

Comment: @PålGD How can I solve it?

Comment: Look at the next uncovered edge and choose which vertex should cover it (try both options).

Comment: What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: @PålGD no, this is a question I had on my first term exam. I tried to use the FPT-Approach by having the paramater = ⌈log |V|⌉ which is a constant, but this was not sufficient

Answer (score 2):

Let the input graph be $G=(V,E)$ and let $k$ be the (maximum) size of the vertex cover of $G$ we are searching for. Proceed as follows:

- If $E=\emptyset$ return the trivial empty solution.
- Otherwise, if $k>0$:

  - Pick an arbitrary edge $(u,v) \in E$.
  - Recursively search for a vertex cover $S$ of size (at most) $k-1$ on the graph $G - u$. If $S$ exists return $S \cup \{u \}$.
  - Recursively search for a vertex cover $S$ of size (at most) $k-1$ on the graph $G-v$. If $S$ exists return $S \cup \{v \}$.
- Return "no solution exists".

The time complexity of the above algorithm can be described by the following recurrence relation, where $n$ is the number of vertices of the input graph for your problem.

$$
T(k) \le 2T(k-1) + O(\mbox{poly}\, n) \quad \mbox{and} \quad T(0)=O(1).
$$

Therefore $T(k) = O( 2^k \cdot  \mbox{poly}\, n )$.
In your case $k=\lceil \log n \rceil$, therefore the overall time needed is $O( \mbox{poly}\, n )$.